# DataGridView ErrorText Tooltip more than 5 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tooltip, datagridviewrow

Is there a way to increase the ToolTip display time on the ErrorText in a DataGridView Row?  Its defaulted to 5 seconds (as all ToolTips are) but you can modify the time on a ToolTip when you create one, but I cant seem to change it on a DataGridView.

EDIT: I am not talking about ToolTipService in WPF, I am using WinForms and using the DataGridVeiwRow.ErrorText field which automatically adds an error icon and a tool tip on mouse over in the Row Header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase ToolTip display time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016007/how-to-increase-tooltip-display-time)

Comment: I am not talking about ToolTipService in WPF, I am using WinForms and using the DataGridVeiwRow.ErrorText field which automatically adds an error icon and a tool tip on mouse over in the Row Header.

Comment: Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5719128/3773066) to use a regular `ToolTip` instead.